# Proving $\sum_{k=a}^{n+a}(-1)^{k-a}*k^{b}*{n \choose k - a}==0\enspace\forall\enspace a,b,n>0\enspace and\enspace b<n$

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

$\sum_{k=a}^{n+a}(-1)^{k-a}*k^{b}*{n \choose k - a}==0\enspace\forall\enspace a,b,n>0\enspace and\enspace b<n$ Is this always true and why?

Full story:
I was trying to prove that if you have a polynomial function of degree n and evaluate the function at n + 2 points with a constant step. i.e: evaluate at X0, X0 + 1 * step, X0 + 2 * step, ...., X0 + (n - 1) * step. And then take the difference of the results and then repeat the same step n + 1 times you will always get a zero.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMhOB.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof by induction over the degree of the function $n$ is probably the easiest way.

Base case when $n=0$, $f(x)=c$ so $f(x)-f(x-1)=c-c=0$ takes only 1 step.

Now assumes the result holds for all $f(x)$ of degree $n$. We look at the $n+1$ degree case.

Let $f(x)=a_{n+1}x^{n+1}+a_nx^n+...+a_1x+a_0$. Then

$$g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)=a_{n+1}(x^{n+1}-(x-1)^{n+1})+h(x)$$

where $h(x)$ has degree at most $n$.

We use binomial theorem to expand $(x-1)^{n+1}=x^{n+1}-...$ so $x^{n+1}-(x-1)^{n+1}$ has degree $n$.

So $g(x)$ has degree $n$ and will take $n+1$ steps to reach $0$.

Now add the extra step for computing $g(x)$ we take $n+2$ steps for $f(x)$ to reach $0$ and by induction we have proven the result.

Comment: Sorry but what's $f(x)$ here and how does this prove the series?

Comment: $f(x)$ is your polynomial function of degree $n$ which you want to prove performing $g(x)=f(x)-f(x-1)$, $h(x)=g(x)-g(x-1)$,... and do this $n+1$ time you will reach $0$. The idea is that after each step you have a polynomial with one degree less.

Answer (score 1):

(Nothing original here)

$\sum_{k=a}^{n+a}(-1)^{k-a}k^{b}{n \choose k - a}
=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{k}(k+a)^{b}{n \choose k}
$.

This is the
$n$-th difference of
$f(x)
=(x+a)^b
$,
which is a polynomial
of degree $b$.
Since the first difference
($f(x)-f(x-1)$)
of a polynomial of
degree $b$
is a polynomial of degree
$b-1$,
the $n$-th difference,
up to $n = b$,
is a polynomial of
degree $b-n$.

Therefore
the $b$-th difference
of a polynomial of
degree $b$
is a constant,
so all higher differences
are zero.